# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Entity Framework EXISTS Query Duration

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to profile a database-first EF SQL query in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application, which seems to be a bit of a time-sink.

After using stopwatch and struggling to the get the granularity I wanted, thus I installed MiniProfiler (amazing BTW if you don't have it, get it).

In a nutshell, the function will receive a comma-delimited string of part id's, and return a string[] of work order base id's;

```
string[] part_array = part.Split(',');
string[] base_id_array = { };

using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("TestDB"))
{
    using (DB_Access.AccessContext db_context = new DB_Access.AccessContext())
    {
        var query = from a in db_context.WorkOrder.AsNoTracking()
                    where part_array.Contains(a.User2)
                    select new
                    {
                        a.BaseId
                    };

        if (query != null)
        {
            if (query.Any())
            {                       
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    Array.Resize(ref base_id_array, base_id_array.Length + 1);
                    base_id_array[base_id_array.GetUpperBound(0)] = item.BaseId;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MiniProfiler shows the following;

[image]

So first EF performs an EXIST query, which takes 147.7ms

Then EF closes the connection, reopens, and performs the actual SELECT query, which takes only 40.4ms

I suppose the question is three fold;

1. Why is EF performing an EXIST query?
2. Why is the query taking so damn long?
3. Why is the connection being closed and reopened within the same using statement?

Comment: How big is database?  How much data is being returned?  Try switching the two using statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is EF performing an EXIST query?

Because you have next line in the code:

```
if (query.Any())
```

This will result in your first query. Materialize query first and use results:

```
var queryResults = (from a in db_context.WorkOrder.AsNoTracking()
                where part_array.Contains(a.User2)
                select new
                {
                    a.BaseId
                })
                .ToList();
foreach (var item in queryResults)
{
    Array.Resize(ref base_id_array, base_id_array.Length + 1);
    base_id_array[base_id_array.GetUpperBound(0)] = item.BaseId;
}
```

You don't need `null` check (cause your are assigning local to a variable and `ToList` returns empty one if no results found in database) and `Any` also (`foreach` will handle that for you).

> Why is the query taking so damn long?

It seems that MiniProfiler does not say how long query takes on the database side, it says how long takes `ExecuteReader`. I will assume that this is some test code which is run once, so it can take so long (longer then select) due to JIT compilation, and the subsequent call takes less time cause JIT compilation as already performed for it. But I would recommend checking queries with database profiler.